# How to extract a number out of a string preceded by zeroes

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I got a string that looks like this `SOMETHING00000076XYZ`

How can I extract the number `76` out of the string using a *shell script*? **Note** that `76` is preceded by zeroes and followed by letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1st solution:*** If you are ok with `awk` could you please try following.

```
echo "SOMETHING00000076XYZ" | awk 'match($0,/0+[0-9]+/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/0+/,"",val);print val;val=""}'
```

In case you want to save this into a variable use following.

```
variable="$(echo "SOMETHING00000076XYZ" | awk '{sub(/.*[^1-9]0+/,"");sub(/[a-zA-Z]+/,"")} 1')"
```

***2nd solution:*** Adding 1 more `awk` solution here(keeping your sample in mind).

```
echo "SOMETHING00000076XYZ" | awk '{sub(/.*[^1-9]0+/,"");sub(/[a-zA-Z]+/,"")} 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `sed` option:

```
echo "SOMETHING00000076XYZ" | sed -r 's/[^0-9]*0*([0-9]+).*/\1/g';

76
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used:

```
[^0-9]*   match zero or more non digits
0*        match zero or more 0's
([0-9]+)  match AND capture any quantity of non zero digits
.*        match the remainder of the string
```

Then, we just replace with `\1`, which is the first (and only) capture group.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'SOMETHING00000076XYZ' | grep -o '[1-9][0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` as

`echo "SOMETHING00000076XYZ" | sed "s/[a-zA-Z]//g" | sed "s/^0*//"`

- The first step is for removing all letters
- The second step is for removing leading zeroes

Comment: @EdMorton nice catch Ed, I think had better using `| sed "s/^0*//"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu grep`:

```
grep -oP '0+\K\d+' <<< 'SOMETHING00000076XYZ'
```

```
76
```

`\K` resets any matched information.

---

Here is another variant of `awk`:

```
awk -F '0+' 'match($2, /^[0-9]+/){print substr($2, 1, RLENGTH)}' <<< 'SOMETHING00000076XYZ'
```

```
76
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Perl as well

```
$ echo "SOMETHING00000076XYZ" | perl -ne ' /\D+0+(\d+)/ and print $1  '
76
$ a=$(echo "SOMETHING00000076XYZ" | perl -ne ' /\D+0+(\d+)/ and print $1  ')

$ echo $a
76

$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'SOMETHING00000076XYZ' | awk '{sub(/^[^0-9]+/,""); print $0+0}'
76
```